# Get raw post request in an ApiController

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, paypal

I'm trying to implement a Paypal Instant Payment Notification (IPN)

The [protocol](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/) is

1. PayPal HTTP POSTs your listener an IPN message that notifies you of an event.
2. Your listener returns an empty HTTP 200 response to PayPal.
3. Your listener HTTP POSTs the complete, unaltered message back to
   PayPal; the message must contain the same fields (in the same order)
   as the original message and be encoded in the same way as the
   original message.
4. PayPal sends a single word back - either VERIFIED (if the message
   matches the original) or INVALID (if the message does not match the
   original).

So far I have

```
        [Route("IPN")]
        [HttpPost]
        public void IPN(PaypalIPNBindingModel model)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // if you want to use the PayPal sandbox change this from false to true
                string response = GetPayPalResponse(model, true);

                if (response == "VERIFIED")
                {

                }
            }
        }

        string GetPayPalResponse(PaypalIPNBindingModel model, bool useSandbox)
        {
            string responseState = "INVALID";
            // Parse the variables
            // Choose whether to use sandbox or live environment
            string paypalUrl = useSandbox ? "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/"
            : "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";

            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(paypalUrl);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));

                //STEP 2 in the paypal protocol
                //Send HTTP CODE 200
                HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync("cgi-bin/webscr", "").Result;

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    //STEP 3
                    //Send the paypal request back with _notify-validate
                    model.cmd = "_notify-validate";
                    response = client.PostAsync("cgi-bin/webscr", THE RAW PAYPAL REQUEST in THE SAME ORDER ).Result;

                    if(response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        responseState = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                    }
                }
            }

            return responseState;
        }
```

My problem is I can't figure out how to send the original request to Paypal with the parameters in the same order.
I could build a `HttpContent` with my `PaypalIPNBindingModel` but I can't guarantee the order.

Is there any way I could achieve this?

Thank you

Comment: Is it not possible to receive it as a string from PayPal, then you can deserialize it yourself, do whatever you need to do to validate it, then POST the string they sent back?

Comment: Thank you, yeah I think but I thought it would be more elegant to use the binding model from asp.net but if there's no other way, I will do deserialize myself.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I believe you should not use parameter binding and just read the raw request yourself. Subsequently, you can deserialize into the model yourself. Alternatively, if you want to leverage Web API's model binding and at the same time, access the raw request body, here is one way I could think of.

When Web API binds the request body into the parameter, the request body stream is emptied. Subsequently, you cannot read it again.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task IPN(PaypalIPNBindingModel model)
{
    var body = await Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); // body will be "".
}
```

So, you have to read the body before model binding runs in Web API pipeline. If you create a message handler, you can ready the body there and store it in the properties dictionary of the request object.

```
public class MyHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected async override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
                                           HttpRequestMessage request, 
                                             CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (request.Content != null)
        {
            string body = await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            request.Properties["body"] = body;
        }

        return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Then, from controller you can retrieve the body string, like this. At this point, you have the raw request body as well as the parameter-bound model.

```
[HttpPost]
public void IPN(PaypalIPNBindingModel model)
{
    var body = (string)(Request.Properties["body"]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, finally I didn't use the model binding.

Comment: I guess there's no way to bind that raw request to a model manually?

Comment: What do you mean by binding raw request to a model manually? If you mean creating an instance of your model object based on the raw request, you have to do that yourself. I'm not familiar with IPN but based on content type, you have to do that. If there is an out of box media type formatter available, Web API will do that for you through binding.

Comment: I made a class PaypalIPNBindingModel and the Web api used to bind it with the paypal request. Now since I use the raw string, can I bind it manually to the PaypalIPNBindingModel like the api used to do?

Comment: Thank you I guess I have to do it myself

Comment: Don't forget to register your new handler in WebApiConfig. 

public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MessageHandlers.Add(new MyHandler ());

        // Other code not shown...
    }
}

Comment: Using the message handler looks as a better option for my purpose as I need the request body in select controller methods. Now, I don't need to implement binder for each of those. Thanks!